# Proper way of logging out + UITableView static cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was wondering how to best practice is to perform a logout, would I just show a new ViewController or how? When I logout I want to get rid of the other viewControllers, you know, kinda reset the app. Or am I just supposed to create a segue back to the login viewcontroller?

In addition can't seem to add an action when I click on a static cell in my MenuTableViewController, how come? I want it to log me out.

Comment: "Best practice" is opinion-based. Do you allow the user to do anything without logging in? For example, Google Maps still allows you to get directions without a sign in. If you do not allow anything, send the user straight to the login screen

Comment: As for clicking on static cell, implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in the table view controller

Comment: Am I just supposed to have a a segue from the cell to the loginscreen?